# Error bounds on the expansion of square root of matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

I'm working on a problem and was lead to trying to find an approximation for the square root of a matrix. I came across a way of doing this using [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus). However, my first attempt at a computation resulted in failure. Did I miss something? --

Wikipedia gives the expansion of the square root matrix as follows:
$$\frac{A^{1/2}}{\|A\|^{1/2}} = I - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left\lvert {1/2 \choose n}\right\rvert  \left(I-\frac{A}{\|A\|}\right)^n = I - \frac 1 2\left(I-\frac{A}{\|A\|}\right) - \frac 1 8 \left(I-\frac{A}{\|A\|}\right)^2 \,...$$
In this post, I'm taking the matrix norm to be the max of the absolute values of the column-sums of matrix $A$.

I thought I might be able to get an estimate of square root matrix by taking the first two terms and using the third term as an error bound. But a simple numerical example appears to not work. I'm not sure if I'm using the expansion incorrectly, or there's some hypothesis I'm missing. In particular for $A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 16 
\end{pmatrix}, \|A\| = 16$.

I get an error:$$\big\|A^{1/2}/\|A\|^{1/2} - I + (I-A/\|A\|)/2 \big\| = 1/8.$$
Error bound using the third term: $$\big\|(I-A/\|A\|)^2/8 \big\| = 9/128.$$

[Remark: This is [cross posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840411/error-bounds-on-the-expansion-of-square-root-of-matrix).]

Comment: the Wikipedia formula you cite says that it needs the eigenvalues of $A$ to lie in the interval (0,2), which does not apply to your choice of $A$.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the wiki article I was using for the formula is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Power_series -- the condition they have is $\|(I - A)\|^n \leq 1$ -- which is true for this case. Where are you seeing the eigenvalue condition you are referring too?

Comment: doesn't it state the requirement that the spectrum of $A$ is contained within a unit disc in the complex plane?

Comment: ah yes -- In this post I am considering a normalized $A$ in the expansion -- $A/\|A\|$  - which is 1/4 and 1 on the diagonal. So for this matrix I believe the spectrum is in the disk centered at 1 with radius 1.

Comment: As another approach, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301272/square-root-of-a-large-sparse-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix?r=SearchResults

Comment: Why do you expect the first omitted term to bound the error ? This series does not have alternating signs, and as far as I understand this result is not true even for scalar inputs.

Comment: My inclination was to think this works like taylor series approximation where the n+1 estimates the error. I suspect I'm wrong somehow though. I thought this might be correct because of the final inequality in the wiki article -- perhaps I could just use a n term taylor appx for $f_k$ and the actual square root for $f_l$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#Continuity_with_respect_to_compact_convergence

Comment: No, the $n+1$st term does not estimate the error in Taylor series, in general. Case in point: $1/(1-x)$.

Comment: But the $n+1$ term bounds the error when Taylor series is within the radius of convergence, right? (The analogous condition holds for the example above)